# Obtener valores de checkbox multiples e insertar

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, checkbox

Tengo una serie de opciones que se cargan desde una tabla en mi bd a una tabla en mi vista, sobre estas filas tengo una serie de checkbox del cual puedo seleccionar uno o mas y esas selecciones guardarla en una tabla con el respectivo id de la opcion...

***Graficamente es asi:***

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Ahora bien, en mi controlador envio la data para llenar la tabla asi:

```
$protecciones = Proteccion::select('caracteristica','id')->get();
$caracteristicas = Caracteristica::select('caracteristica','id')->get();
```

return view('ejecucion_mantenimientos.create', compact('protecciones','caracteristicas'));

y en la vista cargo dicha tabla con un foreach y escribo los inputs en cada columna de la fila:

```
  @foreach ($caracteristicas as $caracteristica )
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>{{$caracteristica->id}}</td>
                                        <td><p>{{$caracteristica->caracteristica}}</p></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="custom-control-lg custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                <input type="text" value="{{$caracteristica->id}}" name="fila[]" hidden>
                                                <input type="hidden" value="false" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_si">
                                                <input class="form-check-input 3-x" type="checkbox" value="true" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_si">                                                </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input type="hidden" value="false" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_no">
                                                <input class="form-check-input 3-x" type="checkbox" value="true" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_no">                                                 </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input type="hidden" value="false" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_na">
                                                <input class="form-check-input 3-x" type="checkbox" value="true" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_na">                                                 </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <textarea name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_obs" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="3" ></textarea>
                                            </div>                                               </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
```

La duda que tengo y no se como encarar/resolver es de que manera inserto la data en la tabla, ya que debo obtener el id de cada fila e insertar los valores del checkbox y si hay un comentario (por cada fila como repito)

***La tabla donde debo insertar la info la tengo asi:***

1. caracteristica_id (que corresponde a la caracteristica que traigo desde la base de datos para llenar la tabla)
2. si (boolean) ->nullable
3. no (boolean)->nullable
4. no_aplica (booelan)->nullable
5. observaciones ->nullable

***EDIT:***: Con la ayuda que me brindaron los coelgas ahora puedo obtener el status de cada checkbox identificado cada uno por el id de la fila (fila_X_codicion), para obtener los numeros de fila estoy probando con un input oculto (id}}" name="fila[]" hidden>) que me geenra un array: fila["1","2"...] con las 12 filas de la tabla, ahora en el metodo store quede perdido porque no sabria como obtener los valores para insertar...Estoy probando asi:

```
 //insertar en tabla mantenimiento_aracteristicas
     $fila = $request->get('fila');
     $carasi = $request->get('material');
     $carano = $request->get('cantidad');
     $carana = $request->get('existencia');
     $caraobs = $request->get();
     $cont = 0;
         while($cont < count ($fila)){

             $MantenimientoCaracteristicas = new MantenimientoCaracteristica();
             $MantenimientoCaracteristicas->caracteristica_id = $fila[$cont];
             $MantenimientoCaracteristicas->si = $material[$cont];
             $MantenimientoCaracteristicas->no = $cantidad[$cont];
             $MantenimientoCaracteristicas->no_aplica = $existencia[$cont];
             $MantenimientoCaracteristicas->observaciones = $ot->id;
             $MantenimientoCaracteristicas->save();
             $cont=$cont+1;
         }
```

Comment: priemro que nada es importante que cada campo que generaste para el formulario tenga un name individual ... y que los datos que enviar a laravel puedas leerlo y convertirlos en los objetos de las entidades... tu ejemplo de codigo no brinda mayor informacion con la cual poder ayudarte y tu escenario no es reproducible.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 gracias por tu tiempo, los nombres de los inputs los genero ahora pasandole el id, añadi una imagen de lo que estoy probando

Comment: tu imagen no aporta nada, ya que no estamos viendo problemas de diseño... y el tema de php y html es que lo que usa el php es el name de los input no el id; incluso por regla el html no puede tener dos elementos con el mismo id...

Comment: añadi la imagen de la salida que me da hacer el submit de prueba, la imagen del comienzo era para dar un panorama de lo que tengo en la vista solamente...quite los id deje solo los name y value de los check asi: value="{{'no'.$caracteristica->id}}" name="no[]"

Comment: y te funciono ???

Comment: logro obtener 3 arrays, uno por cada opcion (si, no, na) y dentro de cada array tengo el name del check (ya es un avance) pero lo que no entiendo es como obtener un array por cada fila de la tabla donde obtenga: [id, check si, check no, check na y la observacion]

Comment: deberias tener el name algo asi: `name="fila1-si[]"` para la siguiente tendria que ser `name="fila2-si[]"`, el numero que usas en la primera comlumna puedes usarlo como contador...

Comment: Usar [botones radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) es mas fácil y mas apropiado para este caso.

Comment: @Sal es que radios no me sirven porque en cada fila puedo seleccionar uno o mas opciones

Answer (score 0):

Al segun como armes tu html en el laravel asi podras acceder a tus campos; puede ser que uses `form()` y te lies, en un php nativo yo haria algo asi:

```php
@foreach ($caracteristicas as $caracteristica )
    <tr>
        <td>
                {{$caracteristica->id}}
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$caracteristica->id}}" name="id_{{$caracteristica->id}}">
        </td>
        <td><p>{{$caracteristica->caracteristica}}</p></td>
        <td>
            <div class="custom-control-lg custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="hidden" value="false" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_si">
                <input class="form-check-input 3-x" type="checkbox" value="true" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_si">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="hidden" value="false" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_no">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="true" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_no">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="hidden" value="false" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_na">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="true" name="fila_{{$caracteristica->id}}_na">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="[{{'obs'.$caracteristica->id}}]" id="[{{'obs'.$caracteristica->id}}]" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="3" ></textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

si ves usaro el id para crear por cada fila un input con un nombre distinto, basado en el numero de `id` de categoria.

tambien implemento un input hidden para enviar un valor por defecto vacio en caso de que el usuario no le de click al checkbox y evitar que php diga que no recibio dicho dato.

no uso `id` como `etiqueta` por que en `html` no pueden existir id iguales.

otro dato es que suelo usar los checkbox para enviar true o false, algo que puedo convertir en un bolean si en la entidad califica como bolean.

en este caso los checkbox no se requieren manejar como array a ellos mismo ya que su valor enviado es un string y solo en teoria debe existir uno a la ves...

de lado de tu php estarias recibiendo algo como:

```
echo form->get('fila_1_na');
```

output:

```
true //string
```

Como obtener un id de la fila o de cada fila, yo paso un camposiempre con el id y una llave dinamica con tal de poder recorrer $_POST y obtener los datos de cada fila ... validando que el nombre de la variable concuerde con el prefijo del campo ene ste caso `id_` es mi prefijo de campo:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'id_') !== false) {
        echo $value
```

Comment: sii ahora puedo obtener cada uno de los check con su id de fila, pero lo que no doy es como hacer para obtener el id de cada fila porque para el insert necesito ese id

Comment: @NicolasEzequielAlmonacid hay agregue como hago yo eso en php, no se si el laravel se pueda hacer algo igual i parecido. imagino que asi como tiene un `form->get()` tambien tienes un `getAll()` creo equivalente a $_POST

Comment: estoy probando de meter un campo oculto: <input type="text" value="{{$caracteristica->id}}" name="fila[]" hidden>, con eso obtengo un array fila["1","2"...] con el total de filas

Comment: asi no se declara un campo oculto mira mi ejemplo, el html.